# Alternate of jmap command required in Linux machine for heap usage

Tags: java, linux

I need alternate of command `jmap -heap -J-d64 $iPid` for heap usage of particular process on Linux machine for Java 1.8.

Comment: What do you mean by "alternate"? Does the command above do what you want? If not, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I don't have utilities like jmap & jstat with java 1.8 package on my Linux machine. I just want same kind of output as this jmap gives for all the process running on my machine. Kindly refer Example 2-22 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html) for sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to server JVM using JMX connection e.g. by using [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html) on your workstation. Open [HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html) and call [`dumpHeap()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap-java.lang.String-boolean-).